# bcrypt fails to build on AWS ELB with Node 8.9.3

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bcrypt

Here's the error from Cloudwatch that's being thrown on deployment -

```
[2018-03-21T08:55:25.254Z] INFO [2599] - [Application deployment v1.1.7@15/StartupStage0/AppDeployPreHook/50npm.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: + /opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py --action npm-install

> bcrypt@1.0.3 install /tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build



Running npm install: /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.5-linux-x64/bin/npm
Setting npm config jobs to 1
npm config jobs set to 1
Running npm with --production flag
Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 695, in <module>
main()
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 677, in main
node_version_manager.run_npm_install(options.app_path)
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 136, in run_npm_install
self.npm_install(bin_path, self.config_manager.get_container_config('app_staging_dir'))
File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
raise e
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.11.5-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 1 (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

I haven't found anything more useful than that; it confirms that it's failed but with very little to go on as to why. I've tried both Node 6.11.5 (as in this instance) and Node 8.9.3 (the newest ELB supports).

Does anyone know why this might suddenly happen? I've tried brand new environments and they hit the same issue when trying to run `npm install --production`. For what it's worth, the same command runs without issue on my Macbook.